# Google Apps Script is replacing content instead of appending text to the draft contents

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

This is my attempt, however, I'm unable to get the draft to update -- I want the text "This Message has been verified" to be added while retaining the draft contents, recipients, and subject.

```
function dlpValidate(e) {
  var toEmails = e.draftMetadata.toRecipients, ccEmails = e.draftMetadata.ccRecipients, bccEmails = e.draftMetadata.bccRecipients, domains = [], uniqueDomains = [];
  var allEmails = toEmails.concat(ccEmails, bccEmails); 
  for (var i = 0; i < allEmails.length; i++) {
    domains[i] = allEmails[i].split("@").pop().split(".")[0];
  }  
  uniqueDomains = domains.filter(listUnique);
  if(uniqueDomains.length == 1 || (uniqueDomains.length <= 2 && uniqueDomains.indexOf("verasafe") != -1)) {
    var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0];
    draft.update(toEmails,"test","This Message has been verified");
    return [notifyYes(uniqueDomains)];
  }
}
```

The @param {event} e is the compose trigger event object, within a Compose trigger function that fires when the compose action is selected: [Reference](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui).

This is the function `listUnique`, called in the main function:

```js
function listUnique(value, index, self) { return self.indexOf(value) === index; }
```

As it's currently written, the function replaces the draft contents entirely, instead of appending it. Additionally, it removes the recipients under CC and/or BCC fields and places them in the TO field.

Comment: There are several variables whose nature is not specified in the question. What is `e` (and as a result, what are`toEmails`, `ccEmails` and `bccEmails`? Strings? Arrays? Also, about `listUnique`, could you provide the code related to this function? Please provide information regarding all this.

Comment: The @param {event} e is the compose trigger event object, within a Compose trigger function that fires when the compose action is selected. Reference:
 
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui

Comment: function listUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

Comment: Have you checked that `draftAccess` is set to `METADATA` in the manifest file? From what I can see, if the function is running at all and if the variables `toEmails`, `ccEmails` and `bccEmails` are getting correctly populated correctly, the draft should update successfully.

Comment: Yes, the function is running, however, The line im facing an issue with is draft.update(toEmails,"test","This Message has been verified"); -- I need to replace this with a working code that:
- Opens the working draft
- Appends to the contents the line: "This message has been verified"
- Retains subject and recipients as-is

Comment: As it's currently written, and if the function is running and the variables are populating correctly to the different email addresses, it should update the draft successfully (if all users share the same domain or if there are only two domains and one of them is verasafe). At least that's the behaviour I'm getting when trying to reproduce your issue and assigning arrays of email addresses to the different variables.

Comment: As it's currently written, the function replaces the draft contents entirely, instead of appending it. Additionally, it removes the recipients under CC and/or BCC fields and places them in the TO field.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer to this question. Did that solve your issue?

Comment: @iamblichus -- Yes, that was perfect - this did resolve my problem. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GmailDraft.update` **replaces all current contents of the draft**, as specified in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#update(String,String,String,Object)). You have to set everything again (subject, content, recipient, cc, bcc, etc.).

So if you just want to append the message "This Message has been verified" to the content and you want to keep everything else as it is, you should first retrieve the data about the current draft, then append whatever you want to this data, and finally update the draft with the appended data.

You could do something along the following lines:

```js
function dlpValidate(e) {
  var toEmails = e.draftMetadata.toRecipients, 
      ccEmails = e.draftMetadata.ccRecipients, 
      bccEmails = e.draftMetadata.bccRecipients, 
      domains = [], 
      uniqueDomains = [];
  var allEmails = toEmails.concat(ccEmails, bccEmails); 
  for (var i = 0; i < allEmails.length; i++) {
    domains[i] = allEmails[i].split("@").pop().split(".")[0];
  }  
  uniqueDomains = domains.filter(listUnique);
  if(uniqueDomains.length == 1 || (uniqueDomains.length <= 2 && uniqueDomains.indexOf("verasafe") != -1)) {
    var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0];
    var message = draft.getMessage();
    var subject = message.getSubject();
    var content = message.getBody();
    // Append "This Message has been verified" to the current draft body
    content = content.concat("<div>This Message has been verified</div>");
    var options = { // Set cc, bcc and body for the updated draft
      bcc: bccEmails.join(","), 
      cc: ccEmails.join(","),
      htmlBody: content
    }
    draft.update(toEmails, subject, content, options); // Update draft
    return [notifyYes(uniqueDomains)];
  }
}
```

#### Reference

- [GmailDraft.update](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#updaterecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

I hope this is of any help.